# JS: How to serve up vanialla JS, HTML and CSS without static html pages?

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to prototype a quick app but don't want to go down the road of using a framework like React or Vue.  I'd also prefer not just creating an `html` file and a `js` file that is imported within the `html`.
Is there a way I can make use of `npm` packages, SCSS and still write vanilla Javascript without the usage of a framework?

Comment: Does this help? https://medium.com/@a.jafari.90/framework-less-single-page-application-a547325f6e0c

Comment: If using a framework will slow you down in prototyping a quick app, then, before you prototype your next one, learn (just the surface) of a framework. Your next prototype will be done in 1/10th the time.

Comment: Yes. You'll want to use something like webpack so it knows how to package your app. If you don't, I supposed you can just throw your `node_modules` in production so the references workout, but I wouldn't recommend that. It'd work though. IMO it's easer to just use a framework since it'll take care of everything for you. If you didn't want to, use webpack or something similar. Downside is you have to do a little more of a setup.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a framework, the most straightforward way to using NPM packages in the browser would be using Browserify. Check out https://medium.com/jeremy-keeshin/hello-world-for-javascript-with-npm-modules-in-the-browser-6020f82d1072 for instance.

Otherwise you can use Gulp,which helps running Browserify, SCSS etc, and use BrowserSync to refresh on changes. But I personally wouldn't go this way: while this is a great way to understand how stuff works, it takes a bit of time to setup properly, and isn't used that much anymore.

My advice is:

- Go with Webpack or Rollup. Seems harder to grasp than Gulp but at the end of the day, learning Webpack is very useful (much more than learning Gulp), for instance if you happen to work on a project that uses it (and there are **so many**).
- Use a backend framework that bundles all this kind of stuff. Like Laravel which uses Mix - *you can even use Mix without Laravel* but there will be a point at which you'll probably need some static data, some routing, interactions... So if you need something more than just hardcoded JSON data, go with a framework. Laravel is great for prototyping but it's not the only one.

Comment: Browserfy is more targeted towards converting node-specific modules into browser-supported modules (and doesn't always work). You're correct with webpack though. Definitely, the way to go if you don't want to use a framework.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit rusted with no framework approaches. Always using Vue/React or Laravel/Lumen "at the very least". Thanks for the clarification !